# In Scala, how can I subclass a Java class with multiple constructors?

Tags: java, scala, constructor, multiple-constructors

Suppose I have a Java class with multiple constructors:

```
class Base {
    Base(int arg1) {...};
    Base(String arg2) {...};
    Base(double arg3) {...};
}
```

How can I extend it in Scala and still provide access to all three of Base's constructors? In Scala, a subclass can only call one of it's superclass's constructors. How can I work around this rule?

Assume the Java class is legacy code that I can't change.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

It's easy to forget that a trait may extend a class. If you use a trait, you can postpone the decision of which constructor to call, like this:

```
trait Extended extends Base {
  ...
}

object Extended {
  def apply(arg1: Int) = new Base(arg1) with Extended
  def apply(arg2: String) = new Base(arg2) with Extended
  def apply(arg3: Double) = new Base(arg3) with Extended
}
```

Scala 2 traits may not themselves have constructor parameters, but you can work around that by using abstract members instead.

(Scala 3 lets traits have constructor parameters.)

Comment: And what if Extended shall have additional parameters or I want to extend Extended with a Grandchild?

Comment: Would love example of how to "work around that by using abstract members."

Comment: @AdamMackler: replace `class A(val b: B)` with `trait A { def b: B }`. It's usually safer to use `def` than `val` here because of initialization order pitfalls. To instantiate, instead of `new A(b)`, you do `new A { val b = ... }`. (`val` may override `def`.)

Comment: Note that this is not equivalent as you cannot instantiate `Extended` with the new keyboard. It [looks like](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-calling-different-super-constructors-td1994456.html) there is no way it equivalently to the Java way.

Comment: That does not work if the whole point of extension is to get access to a protected value.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT** - *this is from a question on the scala mailing list which I thought was duplicated here. My answer relates to providing three different constructors (i.e. replicating the Java design), and not extending the class*

Assuming that each of your constructors ultimately create the *state* `S` of the object, create a companion object with "static" methods to create this state

```
object Base {
  private def stateFrom(d : Double) : S = error("TODO")
  private def stateFrom(s : Str) : S = error("TODO")
  private def stateFrom(i : Int) : S = error("TODO")
}
```

Then create a private constructor taking the state and (public) overloaded constructors which defer to the primary constructor

```
import Base._
class Base private(s : S) { //private constructor takes the state
  def this(d : Double) = this(stateFrom(d)) 
  def this(str : String) = this(stateFrom(str))
  def this(i : Int) = this(stateFrom(i))
  //etc
}
```

Comment: You're changing Base, so this answers a rather different question. It's a good answer to that other question, though :-)

Comment: Yes - the question on the mailing list was not as clearly written as this one!

Comment: That was not the question

Answer (score 2):

I would pick the most generic one (in this case, String) and do the internal conversion yourself if it meets the other criteria.

Although I admit this is not the best solution and something strikes me as wrong about it. :-(

Comment: The thing that's wrong is that it assumes that "the most generic one" is a valid concept.  It's not.  Different constructors can do completely different things.

Comment: @JamesMoore Point very well taken. Clearly, one needs to be aware of the behavior of the various constructors to influence your decision. However, it would be a large violation of the principle of least surprise if, given `double d` that `new Base(d);`, `new Base((int)d);` and `new Base(String.valueOf(d));` did not all do the same thing. Of course it's not a guarantee, but if they're doing different things, there should be different classes. Now, if only all code followed predictable design principles... :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a silly answer that would probably work somewhat but might be too much effort if the Java class has way too many constructors, but:

Write a subclass in Java that implements a constructor that takes all the inputs the various other constructors would and calls the proper constructor of its superclass based on the presence or absence of inputs (via usage of "null" or some sort of sentinel values), then subclass that Java class in Scala and assign the sentinel values as default parameters.