# Multiple Constructors in Scala should call different super methods

Tags: java, inheritance, scala, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Scala, how can I subclass a Java class with multiple constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299776/in-scala-how-can-i-subclass-a-java-class-with-multiple-constructors)

Hello all clever people

I'm currently having a little problem where I need to invoke different super methods based on which constructor I invoke. 
In short it is something like this:

```
class HelpfulJList(model: ListModel) extends JList(model) with MouseListener {

    def this() = { //Call super wihtout arguments -> JList()}
}
```

How can this problem be solved?
Thanks in advance.
Regards Stefan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar / related question: [In Scala, how can I subclass a Java class with multiple constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299776/in-scala-how-can-i-subclass-a-java-class-with-multiple-constructors)