# What is the best way to extend a Java Exception in Scala properly?

Tags: scala, exception

I'm trying to find the simplest yet proper way to extend a Java `Exception` in Scala.  For example, the following is not correct because `new Exception(null, cause)` and `new Exception(cause)` have different behavior according to [`Throwable.java`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Throwable.java#Throwable.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.Throwable%29):

```
class InvalidVersionException(message: String = null, cause: Throwable = null)
  extends IllegalArgumentException(message, cause) {
  def this(message: String) = this(message, null)
  // This is not same with super(cause)
  def this(cause: Throwable) = this(null, cause)
}
```

Because I know `Throwable(cause)` sets the message to `cause.toString()`, I came up with the following:

```
class InvalidVersionException(message: String = null, cause: Throwable = null)
  extends IllegalArgumentException(if ((message eq null) && (cause ne null)) cause.toString else message, cause) {
  def this(message: String) = this(message, null)
  def this(cause: Throwable) = this(null, cause)
}
```

However, this still has:

```
if ((message eq null) && (cause ne null)) cause.toString
```

which was duplicated from `Throwable.java`.

Is there a better way to extend an `Exception` without any code duplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer by @Shadowlands, I ended up with the following:

```
class InvalidVersionException(message: String, cause: Throwable = null)
  extends IllegalArgumentException(message, cause) {
  def this(cause: Throwable) = this(if (cause ne null) cause.toString else null, cause)
  def this() = this(null)
}
```

.. which saves 54 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you should be able to just change the cause-only constructor to:

```
def this(cause: Throwable) = this(cause.toString, cause)
```

EDIT: To handle null cause:

```
def this(cause: Throwable) = this(if (cause == null) "(no message)" else cause.toString, cause)
```

Replace "(no message)" with null (not recommended) or whatever text you feel is appropriate.

Comment: It will raise a `NullPointerException` if `cause` is `null`.

Comment: @trustin Fair point. Have edited my answer with one way of dealing with that.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
trait InvalidVersionException extends IllegalArgumentException

object InvalidVersionException {
  def apply(msg: String) = new IllegalArgumentException(msg) with InvalidVersionException
  def apply(cause: Throwable) = new IllegalArgumentException(cause) with InvalidVersionException
  def apply(msg: String, cause: Throwable) = new IllegalArgumentException(msg, cause) with InvalidVersionException
}
```

(via "[In Scala, how can I subclass a Java class with multiple constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299776/in-scala-how-can-i-subclass-a-java-class-with-multiple-constructors)")

Comment: I'm unsure if it's a good idea to make an exception a trait.  Doesn't it really mean any random class can extend it?